# Can I stop Nethack from generating or loading bones files on Linux?

Tags: nethack

I prefer not to play with bones, so I tried setting `OPTIONS=bones:no` in my `.nethackrc` file. When I load nethack (the version compiled from source), it just tells me "Bad syntax in OPTIONS in .nethackrc: bones:no.", even though it worked when I put it in my `defaults.nh` file on Windows. All of my other options work properly, so it seems like this one is the only problematic one. I even tried using the nethack.alt.org git repository for the source code, and it still doesn't recognize the option. Is there an option I can set to do this on Linux?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to run a script that deletes all the bones level files after each time you run nethack?

Comment: In most cases, probably. In my particular case, due to my computer's configuration and the way nethack was installed, my main user had execute permissions for nethack but no write permissions in the folder, and because of the way character names are chosen, I didn't want to play as root.

Comment: murgatroid99: My *nix is rusty, but couldn't you give the script write permissions for that folder via sudo or root, but run it as a lower-level user? Or, more easily, edit your .nethackrc to move the bones folder to say, /dev/null or at least somewhere you have write permission? It doesn't have to stay with the rest of your nethack stuff.

Comment: I'm not actually sure how using sudo in a script works, but I don't think it's that simple. And what you describe isn't an option in .nethackrc. That file only lets you change [predefined options](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Options).

Comment: BONESDIR is an option on windows, along with HACKDIR, LEVELDIR, SAVEDIR, LOCKDIR, and TROUBLEDIR. Is this not the case on *nix? 

It can be done with a script, though doing it properly would be a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to achieve this by manually modding my source files. In particular, I modified the `src/bones.c` by replacing the function body of `can_make_bones()` with

```
#ifdef BONES
  // the function body
#else
  return FALSE
#endif
```

And I just did not `#define BONES` anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

`bones` is not an option for vanilla nethack.

It is an option, however, in the nethack.alt.org server, which make their source available via git on [this repo](http://alt.org/nethack/nh343-nao.git), if it bothers you.

An alternative would be to reinstall nethack and/or revert any changes to `nhdat` made after each session of play, though this will also remove high scores, etc. If you kept a copy of the "default" or "clean" version in your home directory, for example, you could copy this over the updated version (containing bones, scores, all other data used in the game) each time your start the game.

Finally, you may un-define `DLB` during the compile (which is defaulted to on, IIRC) so that the files in `/usr/lib/nethack` are not concatenated as `nhdat` and will instead appear as files starting with `bones` in that directory and you can then remove them manually before or after each play-through.

Comment: Building NAOhack for a machine that's not configured exactly like NAO is, unfortunately, non-trivial. As far as I can tell the patch that adds the `bones` option is also not available separately on bilious, although I could just be having trouble with the search interface.

Comment: Yes, I tried using the NAO version from their git repo, and it still tells me that the `bones:no` option has bad syntax. Everything else still works though.

Comment: Also, the bones files are already generated as separate files prefixed with "bon", but I would prefer to just not have them at all.